# Why does compiling substrate require nightly toolchain?

Tags: rust, compilation

```shell
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly
```

Why can't the stable toolchain be used to compile, what I beleive is the runtime to WASM? Why is nightly needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [doesn't require nightly anymore](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13580), now substrate compiles with stable rust compiler of at least version 1.68

The original requirement was because [important features were not yet stabilized](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/1252) when the project started.